# phonetic hebrew how to build a rational consensus?

Tags: support, transliteration

I know that the following may show strange.

The phonetic hebrew for a specific language may change. We vrite it differently in French, in English or in Italian.
Many point interest me. the "ת" and the "תּ".Is adapted in English because there is the T and TH. In some region of Italy (Toscana, sometime the T is transformed to 'th' english) But in many languages the T is fixed and it seems strange to transcrive 'ת' by ss. "ph and p" for "פ ופּ"
the "אָ" also, in France, there are regions with changes of the A in diverse cases. So, Ka/omats may be A. 
tsere in ad holam too. In english A may be as an ashkenazi "Tseyre", O may be as a yeki haolam. 
(off topic In German the u may be with 2 points at the top as a french U. )

What are the better choice? What is statistically the frequently choice? What people prefer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guidelines for Hebrew Use](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/430/guidelines-for-hebrew-use)

Comment: I read the references that you send me. It's not self-evident. Is that clear to you?

Answer (score 6):

We've not decided on a transliteration scheme, and, pending such decision, we tend to respect authors' choices of transliteration, afaict. Nonetheless, the site's language is English. Therefore transliteration should be into English IMO, and I've changed *ch* (the French transliteration for the Hebrew letter *shin*) to *sh*.

Comment: See for example, in English Language, the difference between "ח" and "ב" is not relevant. And people translate indifferently by "ch", in French language, there is not this and not this not חיך and not גרון. So it is not possible to make transliteration and we may invent.

Comment: So the transcription become not Phonetic but semi-etymological. For example H and ח. Q and ק.In Italian the old texts transcript  ע to gn. Perhaps a consensus not really phonetic is better. The CH for ח in English may lead to orthographic error in Hebrew. (הגיגים I feel that it is an open and interesting topic.)